# Javascript Multiple Divs same classname but different id's. Always returns last div on clicking any of them

Tags: javascript, html, nested, createelement

I feel silly asking this question. I have a javascript problem that I have been trying to solve since spring break.

I dynamically create divs to contain ratings for a product. But when I click on one of them, it always returns the last one.

```
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {

        // Create Class called divReview
        var divReview = document.createElement("div");
        divReview.className = "divReview";

        counter_ratings++;
        var s = counter_ratings.toString();
        divReview.id = "ratings" + s;

        divReview.innerHTML = divReview.id;

        $( divReview ).click(function() {               

            alert("You clicked " + divReview.innerHTML);            
        });

        mainContainer.appendChild(divReview);
    }
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alvasay/a9GZq/4/

I am pretty sure this is a simple problem, but I just can't see where I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mglison said, late binding.  Alternative solution though is to use `this` in place of `divReview` in your click handler to reference the element being clicked.

```
$( divReview ).click(function() {           
    alert("You clicked " + this.innerHTML);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9HAH/

Comment: I really like this solution, it's very simple. My friend suggested to pass the event object to the function, as in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a9GZq/8/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing late binding.  At the time the function is called, the value of `divReview` is the last value it had in the loop.  I've solved it by creating a function which wraps the actual function to return so that you get the correct value from the closure:

Essentially, the code is something like:

```
for (...) {
    ...
    var funcMaker = function(divRev) {
        return function() {
            alert("you clicked " + divRev.innerHTML);
        };
    };

   $( divReview ).click(funcMaker(divReview));

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9GZq/9/

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had something to do with late binding, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it anyway. Last night I sort of solved it by passing the event object to the function $( ".divReview" ).click(function(event) {}, but I think your solution works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problem mentioned by mgilson, you have an odd mix of plain JS and jQuery. Here's a shorter version

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var divReview = $('<div id="ratings' + i + '" class="divReview">ratings' + i + '</div>');
    $('#gameContainer').append(divReview);
    divReview.click(function() {           
        alert("You clicked " + this.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that is a much cleaner code. I tend to mix Javascript and JQuery, but I need to just stay with JQuery as it is easier to use. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: btw, you may also prefer jQuery's text() for your definitive version